# How to give each variable a different color?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to have a vim color scheme where each variable is given a unique color?

If so, how?

This feature would be really helpful when visually scanning code.

(I think I saw this feature in KDevelop.)

Comment: You can add the color scheme to `.vimrc` from this link. https://github.com/flazz/vim-colorschemes

Comment: You probably have to write this one yourself, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704434/is-there-any-way-to-highlight-multiple-searches-in-gvim @Ramesh If those are just vim color schemes, they will not do what the question is asking for.

Comment: @goldilocks, yeah I realized it after posting that comment :)

Comment: SEO: This process is known as `semantic highlighting`.

Answer (score 1):

In Vim, syntax highlighting is a two-stage process:

1. a *syntax script* (for a particular language) defines the parsing rules and with that determines what can be distinctly highlighted. There's usually an abstraction layer where individual elements are *linked* to logical highlight groups.
2. your *colorscheme* (or the default one) assigns certain colors (depending on the capabilities) to the highlight groups.

Usually, all variables are assigned the same `mylangVariable` highlight group. To enable individual highlighting here, a different, dynamic (!) syntax plugin would be required. Though there recently have been attempts to highlight syntax scopes in Javascript, I haven't seen any syntax plugin of what you have in mind.

#### Alternative

If it's okay to *manually* highlight the individual variables, there are plugins for that, e.g. my [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)